# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:81/controllers/chatController

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongodb-atlas

Currently, I am connecting a one to one chat with mongodb.Atlas cluster. I have a script.js file and I'm trying to call controller's function from there. I am receiving the following error...

[image]

I have tried to import the controller

```
let log = import('../controllers/chatController');
```

and whenever the msg is sent from a user

```
    $scope.sendMsg = ($event) => {
        const keyCode = $event.which || $event.keyCode; 
        if (keyCode === 13 && $scope.message !== null) { 
            socket.emit('getMsg',{
                toid : $scope.selectedUser,
                msg : $scope.message,
                name : $scope.username
            });

            log.createListing($scope);
            $scope.message = null;  
        }       
    };
```

Following is the directory 
[image]

Any idea how to import chatController? So that I could use createListing function?

Comment: First of all you need to adding the .js extension if you want to import files in the browser. How are they served from the server? Secondly, are you sure the controller is a front-end JS and not back-end? Where did you get those files...

Comment: If you're using mongodb dependency, i'm pretty sure it's backend. so you need to require it in the same files as your server code.

Comment: @zavr Now I have changed import to require and now I'm getting a different error 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

and

"Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=app&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined"

Comment: yeah because you're trying to use backend code in your frontend. there's 2 parts to your app: a server, and front-end. DB code has to go into server.js, or utils/routes

Comment: okay @zavr I will do that and will update you. Thanks

Comment: @zavr Can you please take a look here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523815/getting-promise-pending-error-at-log-save-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You might just have to add `.js` extension.</strike>

---

Update your `utils/routes.js` with database code instead, because at the moment you're putting DB logic into browser JS.