# Getting "Promise { <pending> }" error at "Log.save();" - Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert, mongodb-atlas

[image]

I am following MongoDB Atlas Blog tutorial to add info into mongodb but I am getting the above mentioned error. I have tried to resolve this error, even tried to then but still getting the same issue... 
Following is my connection file

```
async function main(){

    /**
     * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
     * See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node/ for more details
     */

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://an:abc@abc-2yzxs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);

    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();

        await createListing(client, 
            {
                msg: client.msg
            }
        );
        return client;

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);


async function createListing(client, newListing){

    const result = await client.db("mydb").collection("mycollection").insertOne(newListing);
    console.log(`New listing created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
}
```

and following is my schema

```
const  mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const  Schema  =  mongoose.Schema;
const  mySchema  =  new Schema(
    {
    msg: {
    type: String
    }
    }
);

let  a  =  mongoose.model("mycollection", mySchema);
module.exports  =  a;
```

My Controller:

```
const  Log  = require('../models/mySchema');
require('../connection');

 function createListing(data){

  let  Log  =  new Log({ msg: data});
    var err = Log.save();

    console.log("err is : ", err)
}
exports.createListing = createListing;
```

this is how I'm calling from server file

```
let log = require('./controllers/myController');

log.createListing(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use mongoose, although you tutorial does. I just use `mongodb`.

```
import { connect } from 'mongodb'

async function main() {
  // try-catch
  const MONGO = 'mongodb+srv://an:abc@abc-2yzxs.mongodb.net/testretryWrites=true&w=majority'
  const client = await connect(MONGO, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true })

  const mongo = client.db()
  const Log = mongo.collection('Log')
  await Log.insertOne({ message: 'test' })
}
```

I know it's different from the problem you have but I just don't know why `mongoose` is needed. It's not really.

Comment: I have tried it and now everything is working. Thanks for saving me again

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **await** before `Log.save()` to log actual value returning by the function instead of `promise pending` you are getting.

```
async function createListing(data){

  let  Log  =  new Log({ msg: data});
  let err = await Log.save();    
  console.log("err is : ", err)
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use await Log.save(); But getting this error

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: @Aq put `async` keyword before `function`. As I have put in the answer.

Comment: @Muhammad Faisal I have changed it to async and with await. console is empty, nothing is displayed and no data has been stored in database

Comment: It means nothing returns from the function you call, please refer to the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany